# I am not a queen, who am I?

Tags: riddle

Here an easy one which dates back to when I was a kid.

I have a crown

Yet I'm not a queen

I have a lot of children

Yet I don't have a husband

Who am I?

Hint:

> I am not a person

Hint 2:

> My children are attached to me

Hint 3:

> I actually have a crown!

Super hints:

> My children are inside of me.

Comment: It feels like this could be too broad. A crown could simply refer to the top of something, in which case a human could be considered to have a crown. Or if you specifically mean some other kind of crown, I mean a princess could wear a crown but not have a husband, or just a mother...

Comment: I agree this is too broad -- "A Roman war hero" could fit, thanks to the Civic Crown and high birth rates in Ancient Rome. (And the fact that soldiers, i.e. men, rarely if ever had _husbands_.)

Comment: @Tas If I’d specify the kind of crown it would be too easy! It’s a popular riddle where I am, I solved it when I was a kid!

Comment: I certainly get that the intention is to be tricky as it can mean different things. I think the hints you've provided help unbroaden the puzzle, though I think they should be part of the puzzle itself (you could quite easily add that it's not a person and the children are attached, even by saying "I keep my children close"). Looking over the 10 answers they mostly seem to fit fine. Puzzles are better (at least on this site) when they have a very clear answer which is kinda of an "aha!", not ones where people are guessing things that fit well.

Comment: If many answers could fit, then the puzzle is under-specified. A well-crafted puzzle will give enough information to rule in the intended solution while ruling out everything else. Also, keep in mind that (at least here) puzzles are not interactive challenges—potential solutions should be testable by referring to *the puzzle*, not by needing a response from the setter as to whether they're right or not. If the puzzle lacks enough specificity to make that determination, then it's probably *too broad*, and any "hints" added to fix that aren't really hints, they're a necessary part of the puzzle.

Comment: @Rubio It’s an Italian riddle, in Italian it’s just like that, I’m sorry if it’s not clear, I’ll be more specific next time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

2nd try:

How about a

> pomegranate ?

It has a crown

It has children

> seeds inside it

and it's no person

Comment: You’re right! Well done!

Answer (score 15):

One possible answer is a

> King (with lots of children)

although I don't know if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Not even close! Try harder!

Comment: @Marybnq This does fit all the clues, no?

Comment: @jafe not at all!

Answer (score 5):

> A  flower.  The petals form the crown and the seeds are the children

Comment: You’re close! But still no...

Answer (score 4):

Are you a:

> Tree?

Line 1-2:

> Trees have a part called the crown.

Lines 3-4:

> Trees can make lots of seeds on their own, their “children,” in a sense.

Comment: Not right but interesting!

Answer (score 4):

It is

> strawberry

Explanation

> It has crown, It has seeds attached to it, Not a person, doesn't have husband and many seeds are attached to the fruit and has crown.

Comment: You are close as well! But that’s not a strawberry!

Answer (score 3):

Are you a

> tooth?

I have a crown

Yet I'm not a queen

> teeth have crowns

I have a lot of children

Yet I don't have a husband

> This might refer to baby teeth

If not, I have a joking answer of

> black widow spider, because the black widow has a "crown" (the timepiece on their abdomen) and don't have husbands because they eat them.

Comment: Not at all! Ahahah but still nice!

Comment: I was going to answer (Rot13: zbhgu) for these same reasons.. Now I've got nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Are you a

> head

I have a crown

Yet I'm not a queen

> a head has a crown

I have a lot of children

> A head has lots of hairs

Yet I don't have a husband (kind of a stretch here but...)

> Widow's peak maybe

Comment: Not at all! Try again!

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> **A Khaleesi?**

Given the timeliness of this post

> In the episode "Lord Snow" from the hit HBO tv series, *Game of Thrones*, Daenerys Targaryen corrects someone who calls her a queen, saying: `Not a Queen, a Khaleesi`

I have a crown

> She wears a crown

Yet I'm not a queen

> She doesn't call herself 'queen', rather a 'Khaleesi', which is the Dothraki equivalent.

I have a lot of children

> She considers her dragons to be her children, hence the style "Mother of Dragons". Additionally, she is referred to as "Mhysa" which in Valyrian literally means "Mother", having freed many slaves.

Yet I don't have a husband

> Her late husband - Khal Drogo - well, he dead man.

Who am I?

> Daenerys Stormborn of the House Targaryen, the First of Her Name, Queen of the Andals, the Rhoynar and the First Men, Lady of the Seven Kingdoms and Protector of the Realm, Lady of Dragonstone, Queen of Meereen, Khaleesi of the Great Grass Sea, the Unburnt, Breaker of Chains and Mother of Dragons

Comment: Just read the "dates back to when I was a child" part which may invalidate this answer, but I mean, "the books" were released a long time ago.

Comment: This is so nerdy, I love this ahaha! But I belong to that 1% of the population who never saw a single episode of game of thrones!

Answer (score 3):

May be answer is

> [Rooster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rooster)

I have a crown

Yet I'm not a queen

> Rooster has crown

I have a lot of children

Yet I don't have a husband

> Rooster has too many children

Comment: Really funny and interesting but wrong!

Answer (score 3):

Who am I? ….drum roll...

> England...The Crown is the British Monarchy

Comment: Not at all, interesting by the way!

Answer (score 2):

Possible answer:

> A grandfather

Consider:

> Proverbs 17:6: Grandchildren are the crown of the aged, and the glory of a son is his father.

Thus:

> Has a crown, is male so not queen and husband, and has at least two generations of decendants

Am I trying too hard?

Comment: It’s not a person, I edited my question!

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> the sun?

It has a crown

> solar corona; corona is italian for crown

It has a lot of children

> the planets

And no queen, no husband, no person

Comment: Not even close!

Comment: By the way I know what corona means, I’m Italian!

Comment: So? Are you the only person on stackexchange?

Comment: No, it was just to say

Answer (score 1):

I thought it was a Seahorse because:

I have a crown

> Seahorses have crowns

I'm not a queen

> male seahorse then

I have a lot of children

> the babies he gives birth

Yet I don't have a husband

> he doesn't

And:

> They live inside me
> The male seahorse carries his children instead of the female

Comment: I promised you, I'm glad now !!!!!

Comment: just a logic thought, nothing much. but thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is a

> Pineapple

Not a person because

> It's a fruit

Children attached to it

> Children are refer to the seed.

Have a crown

> It is Pineapple crown !!

Comment: You are very very close! Still, the children clue doesn’t match...

Comment: My children are attached to me - The crown is the children. those crown used for 
re-plant. it's attached to the fruit.

Comment: In my riddle the crown and the children are different elements, let me update my question! By the way good job, you’re on the right way!

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling your intended answer is:

> tomato
>  [image]

since it has a little crown shaped appendage on top and lots of seeds inside.

But there are lots of potential "right" answers that fit this clue as written.

Answer (score 0):

Could you be

> The "Queen" of fruits; mangosteen?

I have a crown

> The crown on a mangosteen

Yet I'm not a queen

> You're like, a fruit?

I have a lot of children

> The fruits inside of you?

Yet I don't have a husband

> You're an independent mama (lol), your seeds do not need sexual fertilisation (according to Wikipedia)

Answer (score 0):

maybe the answer is:

> Pitaya

my explanation:

> I have a crown

look:

> It can completely be considered a crown:[image]

---

> Yet I'm not a queen ,I have a lot of children

What can be done but

> fruit can not be considered a queen,Indeed, it has many seeds

---

> Yet I don't have a husband. The fruit reproduces through the pollination of its flowers, so it has no husband

Answer (score 0):

Are you a

> Russian Doll

I have a crown

> Top of the head

Yet I'm not a queen

> It’s not a queen

I have a lot of children

> Lots of children inside (hint 4 too)

Yet I don't have a husband

> Toys don’t have husbands

Answer (score -1):

The answer is:

> Plumpkin

Explanation:

> It has a crown
>
>  It has children
>
>  and it's no person